# jquery prepend then animate div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, prepend

hey I have a div that I'm prepending to the body of my HTML doc, after I prepend it I'd like to run an animation function on it, but for some reason the animation never fires.

Right now I'm chaining them together like so:

```
        $(".role-1").prependTo("body").animate({
            position:fixed,
            top:0
        },{
            duration:300,
            queue:false
        });
```

The prepend works fine, the animation just never runs, I'm not sure why, any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: You should post a demo. There's too many other factors that can be coming into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the position to fixed with .css like this

```
$(".role-1").prependTo("body").css({position:"fixed"}).animate({
        top:0
        },{
        duration:300,
        queue:false
});
```

CSS

```
.role-1{
  top:500px;   //if it is 0px it will not animate
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pNBQk/

Comment: it can work with animate but you need to set a default position in the css like this [http://jsfiddle.net/pNBQk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/pNBQk/1/) but i use .css to set the default position to fixed in the answer

Answer (score 1):

[I think this is what you were trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/M3kM3/)

JS:

```
$('<div>').prependTo("body").animate({
    top: '40px'
}, 300);
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
```

This, down here, will work, but there is no animation because the  I created has no height or width and is already positioned at the top of the body.

```
$("<div></div>").prependTo("body").animate({
    position:'fixed',
    top:0
},{
    duration:300,
    queue:false
});
```